# What's the most likely source of this warpage?

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, sla, warping

I've asked about this first printing project of mine before, and made progress in exposure, orientation, and supports. But as the photo shows, something is still causing the objects to warp (badly) during printing. They looked like this as soon as the build plate lifted and the job was done. I cured them right on the plate to avoid introducing any more warp during removal.

I don't know if large, thin-walled objects are just prone to this in resin printing - if so, I'll need to rethink my design.

The irregular thickening around the supports (left sides) is another topic I have open, so this question is just about the warping.

Do ask for any details you would like to help the discussion.

Regards!

*The results, and their print orientation:*
[image: What should be a nice box..]
[image: The print layout]